# Angular-material autocomplete does not show options of listbox

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material

In my Angular 5.1.1 I'm trying to add a autocomplete component. I used Angular Material components before, so I followed their documentation. I included the necessary imports, typescript code and html code. But when I give focus to the input nothing happens, no listbox is shown.

I added to needed imports such as ReactiveFormsModule, MatAutocompleteModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule.

I also tried the same in an Angular 7 application and it works fine there.

component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Select company" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of testCompanies" [value]="option">
          {{ option }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
```

component.ts

```
export class EditModalContent /* implements OnInit */ {
testCompanies: string[] = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];
myControl = new FormControl();
filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
```

In the DOM I don't see any options added to mat-autocomplete and the size seems to be 0x0.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**:

After searching a while through the DOM and comparing with the Angular-Materials example, I discovered that it is shown in a cdk-overlay-container. The issue now is that I'm trying to show this in a Modal, so it is shown in the background. But it is definitely there!

I tried to play with the z-index, but it does not work.

Does anyone as an idea?

Comment: Can you please provide minimal working example in stackblitz?

Comment: @yurzui I tried to set it up in Stackblitz, but it did not succeed with the modal.